# Flask - Uploading a file via Curl

Tags: python, curl, flask

I am trying to upload a file via curl to my flask application. I get no errors, but the curl command ends up sending a blank file, or the flask code doesn't read it properly.

The following is the flask code:

```
#Upload a new set of instructions for <ducky_name>. 
@app.route('/upload/instructions/<ducky_name>/', methods = ['POST'])
def upload_Instruction(ducky_name):
    file = request.data
    print("file: ", file)`
    path = os.getcwd() +/files/" + ducky_name + ".txt"
    with open(path, "w") as f:
        f.write(file)
        print("f: ", f)
        f.close()
        return "Success"
```

And the following curl command is:

```
curl -X POST -d @test.txt http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload/instructions/test1/
```

This is the directory tree:

```
├── README.md
└── server_app
    ├── app
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── routes.py
    │   └── routes.pyc
    ├── files
    │   ├── test1
    │   ├── test1.txt
    │   └── test.txt
    ├── __pycache__
    │   └── server_app.cpython-36.pyc
    ├── server_app.py
    └── server_app.pyc
```

Is it a problem with the `file = request.data` line?

Comment: What does your project directory structure look like?

Comment: Thanks for providing that but could you please edit your original post and add it there since it allows formatting and makes it easier to read

Comment: Sorry about that

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your question correctly. You have a running flask application. When you send it a curl command like above you want it to upload the file test1.txt into your files directors?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this changes and let me know if it works

Add these two lines after your "app = Flask(**name**)" :

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'files'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
```

---

Make the following changes to your routes:

```
@app.route("/upload/instructions/<ducky_name>", methods=["POST"])
def post_file(ducky_name):
    """Upload a file."""

    file = request.files['secret']
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], ducky_name))


    # Return 201 CREATED
    return "", 201
```

---

Where test.txt is the original name of your file that you are uploading and newname.txt is the name of the file you want to be saved as after uploading

```
curl -F  secret=@test.txt  http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload/instructions/newname.txt
```

Comment: @MartinHarvey Please marked the answer as accepted if the solution worked for you , as this will help future visitors find the right solution to this question/similar type question